# How can I deal the flash when I turn back to a Activity has DrawerLayout?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, drawerlayout, android-transitions

I use A `DrawerLayout` in `ActivityA`.

I open the `Drawer` at first. When I `click` a `item` on `Drawer`, I skip to `ActivityB`.

In `ActivityB` ,I close the `Drawer` by `EventBus`. When I `click` the back `button`,`ActivityB` move out,and `ActivityA` move in.

But the screen flash once when `Activity` move in.

I know it's because that when I open a `Drawer`,`ActivityA` dark down.

When I turn back, `Activity` become normal because the `Drawer` is closed.

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: So basically, you want to remove the effect of opening an activity?

Comment: No. I just don't want the page to flash when I turn back from the second Activity.The flash is cause by DrawerLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the animation of the `ActivityA` by setting a theme with this item:

```
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
```

Then implement your own animation. Something like a fast fade in would work.

Comment: No. I just don't want the page to flash when I turn back from the second Activity.The flash is cause by DrawerLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove these lines from `DrawerLayout` tag.

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
```

The flash effect will be remove when you turn back. Hope it works on your side.